# Distinguishing between 'Null' and '0' when taking the sum of a range of columns

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to distinguish between no input or "Null" and the input of something including the number `0`.

I wrote a public function called "ZeroToAppear" that works well enough when used with Index Match Functions by returning the number 0 as a string, but it will not work along with a sum function which is common in financial budgets:

```
Public Function ZeroToAppear(x As Variant) As Variant

    If IsNull(x) Then
            ZeroToAppear = Null
    ElseIf x = 0 Then
        ZeroToAppear = CStr(x)
    Else
        ZeroToAppear = x
    End If
End Function
```

I have rationalized that the problem is that excel automatically considers null as a 0 in order to avoid ArgumentNullExceptions.

So I am trying to write another Macro that will work when taking the sum of a range that can distinguish between no input and 0 or greater input since the sum of cells with no input automatically equals zero in excel and I would like it to report null or even better report false in order to not do the sum at all.

I have started writing a function that tests each cell in the range that I would be summing to see whether it is null, error, or something. If it is null or error, I want it to report null into a test array. If there is some other input I want it to report whatever that input is into the test array. Then I want to identify if the entire test array is reporting null to make my original function false & not run the sum in the range that I am testing but if there are other values then the function should return true and the sum can be run.

```
Public Function NullOrErrorFalse() As Variant

Dim arrOutput() As Variant
ReDim arrOutput(n) As Variant
n = 0
For Each cell In NullOrErrorFalse()
  If IsNull(cell) Then
     arrOutput(n) = Null
  ElseIf IsError(cell) Then
     arrOutput(n) = Null
  Else
     arrOutput(n) = cell.Value
  End If
n = n + 1
Next cell


Sub test(arrOutput())
If arrOutput() = Null Then
  NullOrErrorFalse = False
Else
  NullOrErrorFalse = True
End If

End Sub

End Function
```

At this point my function won't compile correctly and being new to VBA and programming in general, I am not sure if my issue is misuse or syntax or order of operations.

Comment: You can't nest a Sub in a Function like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there is programming flaw due to misunderstanding VBA syntax.

> ```
> Public Function NullOrErrorFalse() As Variant
>     Dim arrOutput() As Variant
>     ....
>     For Each cell In NullOrErrorFalse()
> ```

`NullOrErrorFalse` is the name of the function, not the parameter you are examining. When changing it, you are actually changing the result. On the other hand, you need to provide your function with the parameter (range) that it will check.

You can do you custom sum as a User-Defined Function (UDF) in this way:

```
Public Function SumOrNull(r As Range) As Variant
    SumOrNull = 0
    For Each cel In r
        If IsError(cel) Or cel = "" Or Not IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
            SumOrNull = CVErr(xlErrValue)
            Exit Function
        End If
        SumOrNull = SumOrNull + cel.Value
    Next
End Function
```

The idea is that as soon as there is any pattern that you dont want, your UDF raises an error, so that Excel displays `#Value`, and the cell using your UDF is considered as erroneous.

Comment: Thank you for offering this alternative function. When I apply this to my spreadsheet with all blank cells, it isn't returning any errors and the sum is still being run.

Comment: That's a bit strange because I tested it with success. Pleae make an additional effort to check if you are using it correctly. Remember, the idea is to enter it as a formula, something like `=SumOrNull(F5:F7)`.

Comment: Thank you ASH, yes I was testing it on a range of cells. But when I put 0 in one of the cells it is reporting back an error also, so this function isn't distinguishing between 0 and null. Or at least it isn't considering 0 as a numerical value.

Comment: So I tried changing the second condition of cel = "" to cel =Null and then no error was produced, but the sum function ran and I didn't want it to in this case.

Comment: No you should not change that. The *zero* thing happening with you does not happen in my own test. Honestly I fail to see the reason, I can only guess it might be a problem of cell formatting in your case.

Comment: I tested your function again in a blank workbook with no formatting at all and it still isn't working. Even when I enter a 1 in one of the cells in the range it is reporting an error. I don't think it is a formatting issue. I did save the workbook as a Macro Enabled Workbook.